# How to generate formatted pdf or eps table using Python?

Tags: python, pdf, presentation

I typically have some data from a simulation that I would like to include in a presentation in the form of a table. Usually I use Open(Libre)-Office Impress for doing my presentation. I then copy-paste from my results to the Impress table. I find this a bit tedious. Since I've already got the results in Python, is there any way I can auto-generate a .pdf or .eps table from these data so that I can just quickly import the .pdf or .eps to Impress?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<plug>I wrote [TableFactory](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/TableFactory) to do this for my websites.</plug> It's a wrapper around ReportLab (at least, the PDF generator class is). You can see some example code and output at http://kstrauser.github.com/tablefactory/ .

Answer (score 1):

The standard way of doing this in Python is [ReportLab](http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/) but installing it, is not so easy nor using it.

I don't know exactly what requirements do have but an workaround would be to generate HTML reports and to convert them to PDF.

Depending on what platform you use, you may have different approaches. For example for OSX is really easy, [/System/Library/Printers/Libraries/convert](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14947/what-are-the-secret-options-of-the-pdf-convert-tool-from-os-x)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Reportlab's open source offerings at http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/

Answer (score 0):

Well, this question had been raised for a long time, but recently I got the opportunity to try out the report lab. The installation is easy and doesn't sweat at all. Just go to their homepage and check out their documentation.

For those people who always jump into the "Getting Started Tutorial" first. You could try going through the simple tutorial at this blog for a better overview, on whether this module suits your need or not.
http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/08/a-simple-step-by-step-reportlab-tutorial/

Happy coding.